# Microsft Windows update KB5009543 : troubles with VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-update

I have installed last Windows update kb5009543, and I have troubles using my vpn (pb L2TP), is there another way than uninstall this update to make the vpn work fine?
Has Microsoft provided any new update that fixes the problem?

My configuration :
Windows 10 family / 21H2 / 19044.1415

Answer (score 2):

That is showing as a known issue with kb5009543.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/january-11-2022-kb5009543-os-builds-19042-1466-19043-1466-and-19044-1466-b763552f-73bd-435a-b220-fc3e0bc9765b

"After installing this update, IP Security (IPSEC) connections that contain a Vendor ID might fail. VPN connections using Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP) or IP security Internet Key Exchange (IPSEC IKE) might also be affected."

You may want to install the February cumulative update kb5010342, it does not show the same known issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-8-2022-kb5010342-os-builds-19042-1526-19043-1526-and-19044-1526-bd5c4434-bec4-42e9-991d-5810d4ec52d9